# Bubble sort using linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to sort an unsorted linked list using the bubble sort method but `void bubbleSort()` function does not display anything and the program terminates, I think there is some Logical error in `bubbleSort()` that needs to be resolved.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void insert_at_end();
void bubbleSort();

struct list{
    int data;
    list* next = NULL;
};

list* first = NULL;
list* last = NULL;

int main(){
    int option;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter 1 to insert at end: ";
        cout<<"\nEnter 2 to Bubble sort: ";

        cout<<"\nEnter your option: ";
        cin>>option;

        switch(option){
            case 1:
                insert_at_end();
            break;
            
            case 2:
                bubbleSort();
            break;
            
            default:
                if (option != 0)
                    cout<<"\nYou Entered wrong value!!!";
        }
    } while (option != 0);
    
    return 0;
}

void insert_at_end(){
    
    // create a new node (Allocate memory)
    list* current = new list;
    
    // take inout from user
    cout<<"\nEnter Data: ";
    cin>>current->data;
    
    if ((first == NULL) && (last == NULL))
        first = last = current;
    else{
        last->next = current;
        last = current;
    }

    //displaying Unsorted list
    cout<<"\nUnsorted List:   ";
    list* interator = first;
        do {
            cout<<interator->data<<"   ";
            interator = interator->next;
        } while(interator != NULL); 
}    

void bubbleSort(){
    
    list* p = NULL;
    list* q = first;
    list* r = q->next;

    if(q=first){
        if(q->data > r->data){
            q->next = r->next;
            r->next = q;
            p->next = r;
            first = r;
        }
    }
    else{
        while(r != NULL && r->next != NULL){
            p=p->next;
            q=p->next;
            r=q->next;

            if(q->data > r->data){
                q->next = r->next;
                r->next = q;
                p->next = r;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //displaying Sorted list
    cout<<"\nSorted List:   ";
    list* interator = first;
        do {
            cout<<interator->data<<"   ";
            interator = interator->next;
        } while(interator != NULL); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if(q=first)`? The condition is true whenever `first` is non-null. If it's a typo and you meant `==`, it is always true - you iniitalized `list* q = first;` just a little bit earlier.

Comment: if `q==first` is true (once you've fixed the typo) and `q->data > r->data` then `p` is null and `p->next` has undefined behaviour. your code would be much easier to read if you used more descriptive variable names than `p`, `q`, `r`.

Comment: The best way to work out pointer-manipulating code is to first solve the problem by drawing boxes and arrows on paper.

Comment: *"........................................."*: you should provide debugging information: sample input, where your code goes wrong, etc... Typing dots just to bypass the call for a well documented question is not the way to go.

Comment: Avoid using global  variables. Don't write functions that operate on global objects.  Also, your code is not protected against the list being empty. Answer the questions asked earlier by others to move on.

Comment: Man !! Please use descriptive names it is very difficult to read the code , and as @AlanBirtles said , follow the changes and please use proper names it becomes very difficult for the other person to answer .!